# Converting JSON data to Python data frame

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to convert JSON data to python data frame.When i'm normalizing JSON data complete data is storing in single record as series object.
Could you please tell me how to convert the following JSON data to Python data frame?

**Code:**

```
[{'Name':"SS",  
  'Order':[{'Type':'DO','Value':'10.11/7654326'},  
           {'Type':'UR','Value':'https://do.org/10.11/765436'}],
  'Order_Type':'dsggg',
  'Performance':[{'Per':{'Begin_Date':'2018-01-01','End_Date':'2018-02-02'},  
                  'Ins':[{'Me':'TT','Sales':2}]}]},
{'Name':"MM",
  'Order':[{'Type':'DO','Value':'10.11/7654326'},  
           {'Type':'UR','Value':'https://do.org/10.11/765436'}],
  'Order_Type':'dsggg',
  'Performance':[{'Per':{'Begin_Date':'2018-01-01','End_Date':'2018-02-02'},  
                  'Ins':[{'Me':'TT','Sales':2}]}]}
```

]

Comment: can you tell us what have you tried till now, in code?

Comment: What did you do to get this ? Please share code as well

Comment: what is the expected Dataframe output?

Comment: Code:                                                                                                   
#Normalizing data
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(list_data)

df = pd.read_json(Items, orient='columns')

import re

print(re.split('[{,|,|,',a))

Report_Item.dtypes

Report_Item.mentions.head(10)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'mentions'

# create a list of strings
columns = ['Name', 'Order','Performance','Sales']
df = pd.DataFrame(response, columns=columns,index=index)
df

Comment: I'm excepting the columns as Name,Do,UR,Order_Type,Beign_Date,End_Date,Sales and values as records.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Pandas if you dont need to use loops to get each.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

data = [{'Name':"SS",  
  'Order':[{'Type':'DO','Value':'10.11/7654326'},  
           {'Type':'UR','Value':'https://do.org/10.11/765436'}],
  'Order_Type':'dsggg',
  'Performance':[{'Per':{'Begin_Date':'2018-01-01','End_Date':'2018-02-02'},  
                  'Ins':[{'Me':'TT','Sales':2}]}]},
{'Name':"MM",
  'Order':[{'Type':'DO','Value':'10.11/7654326'},  
           {'Type':'UR','Value':'https://do.org/10.11/765436'}],
  'Order_Type':'dsggg',
  'Performance':[{'Per':{'Begin_Date':'2018-01-01','End_Date':'2018-02-02'},  
                  'Ins':[{'Me':'TT','Sales':2}]}]}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(data), orient='columns')
```

Comment: But inside the Order or Performace columns are nested.
Name Order                                                             Order_Type Performance
SS     [{'Type': 'DO', 'Value': '10.11/7654326'}, {'T... dsggg            [{'Per':{'Begin_Date': '2018-01-01', 'End_Dat...
1
MM
[{'Type': 'DO', 'Value': '10.11/7654326'}, {'T...
dsggg
[{'Per': {'Begin_Date': '2018-01-01', 'End_Dat...

Comment: The you must do a for loop and get each on levels

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45168524/deeply-nested-json-response-to-pandas-dataframe

Comment: In for loop it is throwing error as 'list' object is not callable.

Comment: I'm trying to extract columns and their corresponding values using For loop.But it is throwing error as list object is not callable. Following is the code.                                                                                    cols = ['Name', 'Do', 'UR', 'Order_Type', 'Begin_Date','End_Date','Me','Sales']
rows = []
for data in temp:
    data_id = data['Name']
    criteria = data['Order']['Performance']
    for d in criteria:
        rows.append([data_id, criteria.index(d)+1, *list(d.values())[:-1]])